# Increment Bitwise

Tags: restricted-source, javascript, atomic-code-golf

Make a function that increments a number using only bitwise, loops, and conditions.

**Rules:**

1. All entries must be as per the language spec defined below.
2. Scoring is not of code length, but of the points for each operation given below.
3. The entry point is `inc(a)`, for "increment and return a".
4. Lowest score wins.

See the example to help with scoring.

**Language Spec (strict JS subset):**

All input is assumed to be signed 32-bit integers, with input being in the range [-2<sup>31</sup>+1, 2<sup>31</sup>-2] ([interval notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_notation#Notations_for_intervals)), with the upper bound to give room for the increment. All output is assumed to be within the range [-2<sup>31</sup>+2, 2<sup>31</sup>-1].

Whitespace is never syntactically significant beyond separating literals, keywords, and newline-ended comments. Booleans for conditions can and may be implicitly converted to integers, with `1 == true` and `0 == false`. All variables are passed by value (as they are all primitives).

Cost is given for each element, with "per use" implied.

Comments: (0 pts)

```
/* like this */
// or this
```

Numeric or variable literal: (0 pts)

```
i, someVariable, 2, etc.
```

Boolean literal: (0 pts)

```
true  // == 1, implicit conversion
false // == 0, implicit conversion
```

- Note: Integer to boolean conversion is as follows (in pseudocode):

  ```
  if 0: true
  else: false
  ```

Grouping: (0 pts)

```
(foo && bar);
```

Function declaration: (0 pts)

```
function foo() { ... } // braces required
function bar(a) { ... }
```

Declare variable: (0 pts)

```
var a;
```

Assignment: (1 pt)

```
var a = 1; // semicolon required to terminate statement
a = 2; // only needs declared once
var b = a;
// b = a = 3; // cannot assign in right side of statement
var c = a << 5;
var d = a ^ (c << 5);
```

Equality/Inequality: (1 pt)

```
x == 1; // equality
x != 1; // inequality
x > y; // greater than
x >= y; // greater than or equal to
x < y; // less than
x <= y; // less than or equal to
```

Logical operators: (1 pt)

- `!a` (not)
- `a && b` (and, returns 1 if both are true, 0 otherwise)
- `a || b` (or, returns 1 if either are true, 0 otherwise)

Bitwise operators: (1 pt)

- `~a` (not)
- `a & b` (and)
- `a | b` (or)
- `a ^ b` (exclusive or)
- `a << b` (arithmetic left shift)
- `a >> b` (arithmetic right shift)
- `a >>> b` (logical right shift)

Augmented assignment: (2 pts)

```
a &= b; // example
```

If statement: (condition value + 1 pt)

```
if (condition) { ... }
if (x == 2) { ... } // worth 2 pts
if (x) { ... } // x is nonzero, worth 1 pt
```

If-Else statement: (condition value + 2 pts)

```
if (condition) { ... } else { ... }
```

While statement: (condition value + 2 pts)

```
while (condition) { ... }
while (x == 2) { ... } // worth 3 pts
while (x) { ... } // evaluation same as in if, worth 2 pts
```

Do-While statement: (condition value + 2 pts)

```
do { ... } while (condition); // semicolon required
```

Return statement: (number of points for statement on right + 1 pt)

```
return foo; // semicolon required, worth 1 pt
return a & b; // worth 2 pts
```

Function call: (number of parameters + 2 pts)

```
foo(); // worth 2 pts
bar(1, 2) // worth 2 + 2 = 4 pts
```

Operator precedence (first to last performed):

1. `( ... )`
2. `~`/`!` (right-to-left)
3. `<<`/`>>`/`>>>` (left-to-right)
4. `>`/`<`/`>=`/`<=` (left-to-right)
5. `==`/`!=` (left-to-right)

   - Note: `1 == 1 == 1` works out to `0 == 1` which is `0`.
6. `&` (left-to-right)
7. `^` (left-to-right)
8. `|` (left-to-right)
9. `&&` (left-to-right)
10. `||` (left-to-right)

**Example scoring:**

This (ficticious) example would score 14 points. See comments for details.

```
function inc(a) {
  var b = a; // adds 1 pt for assignment
  if (!a) return 0; // adds 3 pts: 2 for if and 1 for return
  while (a & b) { // adds 3 pts: 2 for while and 1 for `&`
    b >>= a ^ b; // adds 3 pts: 2 for augmented assignment, 1 for `^`
    a = b << 1; // adds 2 pts: 1 for assignment, 1 for `<<`
  }
  return a ^ b; // adds 2 pts: 1 for return, 1 for `^`
}
```

Comment: Is there a Javascript-only requirement? If so please make this explicit in the question and add a `javascript` tag. Note also that language-specific challenges are rather lame, especially given that many languages share this same set of operators.

Comment: @PaulR And even if they didn't, I think the wording is good enough the prevent any loopholes with, let's say, J.

Comment: Does this need to work for negatives? Are numbers limited to 32 bits?

Comment: Does JS implicitly cast between Booleans and numbers?

Comment: Yes, but treat them as integers in this context.

Comment: @xnor No and yes.

Answer (score 5):

## 10

Works for negative numbers.

```
function inc(x) 
{ 
    if(x & 1)                       // 1 + 1
        return inc(x >>> 1) << 1;   // 1 + 3 + 1 + 1

    return x | 1;                   // 1 + 1
};
```

Answer (score 2):

## 11 points (also works for negative numbers)

```
function inc(a) {
  var t = 1;             // 1 pt
  while (a & t) {        // 3 pts
    a &= (~t);           // 3 pts
    t <<= 1;             // 2 pts
  }
  return a|t;            // 2 pts
}
```

I thought this was supposed to actually increment the number it was called on, but I am not familiar with a way to pass integers by reference in JS.

Comment: It works when converted to C/C++. Good answer

Comment: No. It only returns the incremented value. JS only has pass by reference for primitives.

Answer (score 2):

### 10 (works for negative numbers)

```js
function inc(a)
{
    var c = 1;                   // 1 
    while (c)                    // 2
    {
        var s = a ^ c;           // 2
        c = (a & c) << 1;        // 3
        a = s;                   // 1
    }
    return a;                    // 1
}
```

Comment: The question mentions that the language spec you need to use is a JS subset, I understood that as a requirement to use JS... but I don't think there's much of a difference here anyway.

Comment: I've converted it to JS now (I *think* - I've never used JS before) - I'll also ask the OP to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

## 11 (Works for negatives)

```
function inc(a) {
    for(var b=1;a&b;b<<=1) {
        a=a^b;
    }
    return a^b
}
```

Comment: How are `for` loops scored?

Comment: @xnor I treated them as `1 + (score for code in brackets)`.

Answer (score 0):

## 10 (13 if it must work for negative numbers)

```
function inc(a){
  var m=1;             // 1pts
  while((a & m)==m){   // 4pts
    m=(m<<1)|1;        // 3pts
  }
  return a^m;          // 2pts
}
```

Comment: It is 13. I clarified...apparently that didn't get caught in the Sandbox phase